# How do I avoid false matches to a chemical formula in scanString with pyparsing

Tags: pyparsing

I am trying to use pyparsing to scan text for chemical formulas. I have the following example code:

```
from pyparsing import *

caps = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
lowers = caps.lower()
digits = "0123456789"
integer = Word( digits )
parl = Literal("(").suppress()
parr = Literal(")").suppress()

element = oneOf( """H He Li Be B C N O F Ne Na Mg Al Si P S Cl
            Ar K Ca Sc Ti V Cr Mn Fe Co Ni Cu Zn Ga Ge
            As Se Br Kr Rb Sr Y Zr Nb Mo Tc Ru Rh Pd Ag
            Cd In Sn Sb Te I Xe Cs Ba Lu Hf Ta W Re Os
            Ir Pt Au Hg Tl Pb Bi Po At Rn Fr Ra Lr Rf
            Db Sg Bh Hs Mt Ds Rg Uub Uut Uuq Uup Uuh Uus
            Uuo La Ce Pr Nd Pm Sm Eu Gd Tb Dy Ho Er Tm
            Yb Ac Th Pa U Np Pu Am Cm Bk Cf Es Fm Md No """ )

separator = Literal( "," ).setParseAction(lambda s,l,t: t[0].replace(',','.')) | Literal( "." )

nreal = (Combine( integer + Optional( separator +\
    Optional( integer ) ))\
    | Combine( separator + integer )).setParseAction( lambda s,l,t: [ float(t[0]) ] )

block = Forward()
groupElem = (Group( element('elem') + Optional( nreal, default=1)('esteq') ))('dupla') | \
     Group( parl + block + parr + Optional( nreal,default=1 )('modi'))
block << groupElem + ZeroOrMore( groupElem )
formula = OneOrMore( block )+ Optional(Or([Literal("-"), Literal("+")]))

s = '''Water is H2O not h2o, methane is CH4 and of course there is PtCl4.
What about H+ and OH-? and carbon or Carbon or H2SO4?'''
for match, start, stop in formula.scanString(s):
  print match, s[start:stop]
```

and it outputs:

```
 [['W', 1]] W
 [['H', 2.0], ['O', 1]] H2O
 [['C', 1], ['H', 4.0]] CH4
 [['Pt', 1], ['Cl', 4.0], ['W', 1]] PtCl4.
 W
 [['H', 1], '+'] H+
 [['O', 1], ['H', 1], '-'] OH-     
 [['Ca', 1]] Ca
 [['H', 2.0], ['S', 1], ['O', 4.0]] H2SO4
```

Which is approximately right, but there are some false hits. For example, W, and the Ca of Carbon should not be listed. I am not sure how to modify the grammar to indicate that Ca in Carbon is not a chemical formula. The parser works perfectly with parseString on just the formulas, but it is not specific enough in mixed text. Any hints on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want all of your formulas to be self-contained letter groups, so just change your formula definition to:

```
formula = (WordStart() + 
           OneOrMore( block )+ Optional(Or([Literal("-"), Literal("+")])) +
           WordEnd())
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That helps a little, but doesn't fix the issue completely. In '''Water is H2O not h2o, methane is CH4 and of course there is PtCl4.
What about H+ and OH-? and carbon or Carbon or H2SO4?''' The following formulas are not found: H2O, OH- and H2SO4. I cannot figure out  why H2O is not found, but OH- and H2SO4 are not found because of the ? at the end.

Comment: I figured out that WordEnd(alphas + alphas.lower() + nums + "-+") is needed here to define what a Word character in a formula is. H2O is still not found for some reason, although curiously, OH2 is.

Comment: it appears that pyparsing.alphas has both upper and lower case letters already, so the alphas.lowers() was unnecessary above.

Comment: I think this finally got me most of the way there by not ignoring whitespace:
chemicalFormula = (WordStart()
                   + OneOrMore(elementRef).leaveWhitespace()
                   + Optional(Or([Literal("-"),
                                  Literal("+")]))
                   + WordEnd(alphas + alphas.lower() + nums + "-+"))

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to make progress on this on your own - welcome to Pyparsing!